# How do I generate YAML containing local tags with ruamel.yaml?

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I'm using ruamel.yaml to generate a YAML file that will be read by [Tavern](https://taverntesting.github.io/), which requires the file to contain a list like this:

```
includes:
- !include vars.yaml
```

Attempting to use any of the usual approaches to dump the data as strings results in [single quotes being added around the tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50996060/python-ruamel-yaml-dumps-tags-with-quotes), which doesn't work when the YAML is ingested by the next tool.

How do I generate a YAML file that contains unquoted [local tags](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2782090), starting with data that is defined in a dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is a better approach, but if you had tried to round-trip your required output, you
would have seen that ruamel.yaml actually can preserve your tagged strings, without you having to
do anything. Inspecting the Python datastructure, you'll notice that `ruamel.yaml` does 
this by creating a `TaggedScalar` (as you cannnot attach attributes to the built-in string type).

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
includes:
- !include vars.yaml
- !exclude dummy.yaml
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)

incl = data['includes'][0]
print(type(incl))
```

which gives:

```
includes:
- !include vars.yaml
- !exclude dummy.yaml
<class 'ruamel.yaml.comments.TaggedScalar'>
```

After inspecting `comments.py` (and possible `constructor.py`), you should be able
to make `ruamel.yaml`'s internal data structure on the fly:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.comments import TaggedScalar

def tagged_string(tag, val):
    # starting with ruamel.yaml>0.16.5 you can replace the following lines with:
    # return TaggedScalar(value=val, tag=tag)
    ret_val = TaggedScalar()
    ret_val.value = val
    ret_val.yaml_set_tag(tag)
    return ret_val

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = dict(includes=[tagged_string('!include', 'vars.yaml'), 
                      tagged_string('!include', 'vars.yaml'),
                     ])
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which also gives:

```
includes:
- !include vars.yaml
- !include vars.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create a YAML file with the required format using the following approach, based on [prior examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46806918/how-to-create-a-custom-yaml-mapping-dumper-for-ruamel-yaml). My approach is more flexible because it allows the tag handle to be an instance property rather than a class property, so you don't need to define a different class for every tag handle.

```py
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML(typ='rt')

class TaggedString:    
    def __init__(self, handle, value):
        self.handle = handle
        self.value = value

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        # I don't understand the arguments to the following function!
        return representer.represent_scalar(u'{.handle}'.format(node),
            u'{.value}'.format(node))

yaml.register_class(TaggedString)

data = {
    'includes': [
        TaggedString('!include', 'vars.yaml'),
        TaggedString('!exclude', 'dummy.yaml')
    ]
}

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

Output:

```
includes:
- !include vars.yaml
- !exclude dummy.yaml
```

I am not sure if this is the best approach. I might be missing a simpler way to achieve the same result. Note that my goal is not to dump a Python class; I'm just doing that as a way to get the tag to be written correctly.